# DataGridView ComboBox column not accepting new values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a `DataGridView` control in my Windows Forms application that allows users to edit product listing. To edit the product category, I want user to add new entries or select from the ones already entered before. To achieve this I added a `comboBox` column that is binded to a `DataSource` that gets the distinct category names from the products table. With the help of some other SO questions I was able make this `comboBox` editable using this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == CategorySelector.Index)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo == null)
            return;
        combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when I try to edit the category `comboBox` column and add new category other than the listed, and when I switch to other cell, it switches back to old category item for existing product or blank for new product. Please tell me how can I add new category through this `comboBox` column?

Comment: Post the codes that you tried to add a Category.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am using auto-generated `DataGridView` methods for adding.

Comment: The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` only shows the items of its `DataSource`. So if you expect it shows a new item in list, you should add a new item to its data source.

Comment: Yeah but how can it be done using `DataGridView`? I want user to edit the comboBox column to add the new category.

Comment: @RezaAghaei please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Good idea, good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it by myself. I implemented the `LostFocus` event of the `comboBox` where I added the code for updating the bound `DataSet` with the new item.

The item is successfully added but one problem still persists. The item is not selected after it's added. `ComboBox` still resets to the previous selection. However, I can select the new item manually. But if you can solve this bug it will become a better UX for the user. Following is how I achieved new item adding:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == CategorySelector.Index)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo == null)
            return;
        combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        combo.LostFocus += combo_LostFocus;
    }
}
void combo_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox c = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (c.FindStringExact(c.Text.Trim().ToLower()) == -1)
    {
        inventoryCategorySet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(c.Text.Trim().ToLower());
        inventoryCategorySet.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```